# Dropwizard url rewriting

Tags: url, jetty, dropwizard

How do I enable URL rewriting in dropwizard? I need to rewrite all urls matching a certain pattern to /.

I'm using dropwizard 0.7.1 and I'm trying to run an Angular.js app in html5 mode in the front-end and this requires url rewriting (see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location under the **Server side** section).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with this: http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

it's very symilar to mod_rewrite.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out how to make it find the `urlrewrite.xml` file. One has to set the base resource using `environment.servlets().setBaseResource(…)` (tested with Dropwizard 2.0.0-rc13).

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `Filter` like this:

```java
environment.getApplicationContext().addFilter(
  new FilterHolder(new Filter() {

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    if (shouldRedirect(request.getRequestURI())) {
        response.sendRedirect("/");
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {}
}), "/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
```

Comment: I don't want to redirect the client, I want to do server side url rewriting. Like mod_rewrite in apache2.

Answer (score 0):

For simple rules it seems to me that the best option is to use the Dropwizard `PathRedirect` [`RedirectBundle`](https://github.com/dropwizard-bundles/dropwizard-redirect-bundle).

- Add `dropwizard-redirect-bundle` to your dependencies
- Register the bundle:

  ```
  @Override
  public void initialize(Bootstrap<?> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(new RedirectBundle(
      new PathRedirect("/old", "/new")
    ));
  }
  ```

It supports regular expressions as well.

Just a note that for this to work with other bundles, such as static assets and HTTPS redirect, order matters. It should be:

- `AssetsBundle` first
- `HttpsRedirect` second
- `PathRedirect` last